# Keep drop-list selection/value upon failed form submission - Laravel 6.x

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have created a submission form in Laravel 6.x, which includes drop-lists, each populated by the database, using a "@foreach" loop in the blade file. Here is my HTML/PHP code:

```
<div id="event-sport">
    <span>Sport:</span>
    <select name="sport">
        <option value="default" selected="selected" disabled hidden>Select Sport</option>
        @foreach($sports as $sport)
            <option value="{{ $sport->id }}" title="{{ $sport->desc }}">{{ $sport->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    @if ($errors->has('sport'))
        <span id="error-msg" style="color:red; font-size:1.5vh;"><br>{{ 'Please select a sport' }}</span>
    @endif
</div>
```

I use the "{{ old('') }}" helper method to keep the other inputs after a failed form submission, in elements like textareas and inputs, but I don't know how to keep the selected option (along with its value) of a drop-list.

**The current behavior of the drop-list is as follows:**

1. Form is loaded - nothing is selected
2. I select an option
3. I submit the form (without properly filling the rest of it so it
   will fail anyways)
4. The form does not return an error message for this drop-list but the
   selection is set to the default ("*Select Sport*")
5. I re-submit the form without touching the drop-list
6. The form returns an error message for that drop-list, asking to
   select an option

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: Hi, look at this link. Maybe it will help you. https://www.5balloons.info/retain-old-form-data-on-validation-error-in-laravel/

Comment: This helped me figure it out, thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured it out, thanks to the [source](https://www.5balloons.info/retain-old-form-data-on-validation-error-in-laravel/) provided by Philip. The answer was pretty easy after all.

All I did, was add `{{ old('sport') == "$sport->id" ? 'selected' : '' }}` inside the `<option>` tag of the select box, inside the `foreach` loop. This line however was a bit changed for the edit form, because there, the values have to be drawn from the database first, and then changed from the 'old' selection.

The **Create** form:

```
<div id="event-sport">
    <span>Sport:</span>
    <select name="sport">
        <option value="default" selected="selected" disabled hidden>Select Sport</option>
        @foreach($sports as $sport)
            <option value="{{ $sport->id }}" {{ old('sport') == "$sport->id" ? 'selected' : '' }} title="{{ $sport->desc }}">{{ $sport->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>

    @if ($errors->has('sport'))
        <span id="error-msg" style="color:red; font-size:1.5vh;"><br>{{ 'Please select a sport' }}</span>
    @endif
</div>
```

The **Edit** from:

```
<div id="event-sport">
    <span>Sport:</span>
     <select name="sport">
         <option value="{{$event->sport->id}}" selected="selected" disabled hidden>{{$event->sport->name}}</option>
         @foreach($sports as $sport)
             <option value="{{ $sport->id }}" {{ $event->sport->id == "$sport->id" ? 'selected' : '' }} title="{{ $sport->desc }}">{{ $sport->name }}</option>
         @endforeach
     </select>

     @if ($errors->has('sport'))
         <span id="error-msg" style="color:red; font-size:1.5vh;"><br>{{ 'Please select a sport' }}</span>
     @endif

 </div>
```

Notice how in the **Edit** form, the addition to the `<option>` tag is `{{ $event->sport->id == "$sport->id" ? 'selected' : '' }}`.